# C++ template declaration with inheritance list

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, declaration, c++03

Is it possible to declare a templated class in C++ along with the classes it inherits from? Basically I want to give the compiler a hint, that my templated class will always inherit another at declaration time.
Maybe some code will clear up why this is a problem for me:

```
template<typename T>
class GrandparentClass
{
public:
    T grandparentMember;
};

//this needs to be only a declaration, since I do not want classes of ParentClass with random T
template<typename T>
class ParentClass : public GrandparentClass<T>
{

};

// this does not work:
//template<typename T>
//class ParentClass : public GrandparentClass<T>;

// this does not either, because then the child class cannot access the variable from the grandparent class
//template<typename T>
//class ParentClass;

template<>
class ParentClass<int> : public GrandparentClass<int>
{
public:
    ParentClass()
    {
        grandparentMember = 5;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class ChildClass : public ParentClass<T>
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << grandparentMember << "\n";
    }
};
```

Also, I cannot use C++ 11.

EDIT:

I found an easy way out of this:

```
template<typename T>
class ParentClass : public GrandparentClass<T>
{
public:
    ParentClass() { ParentClass::CompilerError(); };
};
```

Just do not define CompilerError() method in the class and everything's fine.

Comment: Yes, that should work. Where do you see the problem?

Comment: No. A class declaration takes the from `class foo;`. Whether template or not, this cannot include a base class. And even if it could, a specialization would still have to include it again.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot change the definition to `template<typename T>
class ParentClass : public GrandparentClass<T>;` I'll edit this in the code

Comment: Why do you want to give the *compiler* such hint? The compiler does not interpret the declarations before it knows the concrete parameter assignment anyway, so it has no use for such hint.

Comment: I want to prohibit the instantiations of ParentClass with typenames different from the ones I've specialized it for, while the grandparent members should still be accessible from the child class. Basically I do not want to provide a definition of ParentClass for any T, just for specific types.

Comment: @lightxbulb, the compiler only looks at the specialization when instantiating the template. Members will be available from whatever base class is declared for each specialization.

Comment: Do you have any idea for a workaround, so that I can prohibit the instatiation of random ParentClass classes while still seeing the members of the grand parent class from the child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class declaration is only really useful for non-value variable declarations, like pointers and references. You can't access the class members or even instantiate it, though. Even if you knew that a declared class inherits from some other one, you still wouldn't necessarily be able to utilize that information in any way.

As such, it's only important for the compiler to know what the class inherits from once it learns its full definition.

---

After clarification in comments: if you want to prevent *instantiation* of a class template with some types, its definition is the place to do it. A simple `static_assert` inside the class body will do the trick; `Boost.StaticAssert` or older SFINAE tricks will do the job for pre-C++11 code.

Comment: @lightxbulb and what it is what you want to achieve, exactly?

Comment: Prohibiting instantiations of ParentClass with typenames different from the ones I've specialized it for, while the grandparent members should still be accessible from the child class. Basically I do not want to provide a definition of ParentClass for any T, just for specific types.

Comment: You can just slap a `static_assert` inside your `ParentClass` then?

Comment: This is a C++ 11 feature I believe.

Comment: @lightxbulb, [Boost.StaticAssert](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) is a definition that works in C++98 just fine except for less obvious error message. Import or copy it into your project as appropriate. It is not complicated.

Comment: @JanHudec I found an easier way out of this, take a look if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with delaying the error to link-time, rather than compile time, you can declare all the member functions of parent in parent.h, provide definitions in parent.cpp, and explicitly instantiate the finite list of classes that you want.

Parent.h

```
template<typename T>
class ParentClass : public GrandparentClass<T>
{
    ParentClass();
};

class ParentClass<int>;
class ParentClass<long int>; // or whatever
```

Parent.cpp

```
template <typename T>
ParentClass::ParentClass() : grandparentMember(5) {}
```

Comment: I got inspired by your solution, but turned it into a compile time error, since they are more readable from my experience.